# Getting Preflight request doesn't pass access control check error while communicating between Spring and Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a custom filter, that checks for the user authentication using Spring 4.2.
While making a request from the angular application, I get the following error:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin http://localhost:4200 has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**

The header included in the angular Application is:

```
const requestHeaderObject = {
   headers: request.headers
              .append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
              .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
              .append('logged_user_id', 'userId')
              .append('auth_token', 'authToken')
}
```

The code of my Filter in Spring is:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    
        //      Fetching all the header params from request
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
        String loggedUserId = null;
        String authToken = null;

        if (headerNames != null) {
            while (headerNames.nextElement() != null && headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                loggedUserId = httpRequest.getHeader('logged_user_id');
                authToken = httpRequest.getHeader('auth_token');
            }
        }
        
        if (loggedUserId == null || authToken == null) {    
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), getErrorDetailsMap());
            return;
        }
        
        ApplicationContext appContext = AppContextConfig.getApplicationContext();
        AccessManager accessManager = (AccessManager) appContext.getBean(AccessManager.class);
        
        if(accessManager.isValidToken(loggedUserId, authToken) == false) {
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), getErrorDetailsMap());
            return; 
        }
        
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

I have done the following but was not successful:

1. Adding @CrossOrigin mapping to all the controllers
2. Adding the following code in my filter:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
```

3. Disabling cors in the security configuration by overriding the configure method as follows:

   ```
    http.cors().disable();
   ```
4. Changed the headers in the angular applications.
5. Also I have tried to write another filter and passing the headers in that filter and calling it before my actual filter.